# pass python arguments with argument name

Tags: robotframework

I am passing arguments to python file from keywords. But can I pass the arguments by giving the name of the argument?

```
test method  ${par1}  True  ${par3}
```

and my python method is

```
def test_method(par1, expected=False, par3=None)
```

Can I pass arguments by giving argument name as per python?
e.g. `test method  expected=True  par3=${par3}  ${par1}`

it is treating it as passed value. If I passed as expected=True I get got positional argument after named arguments.

Comment: Did you try it to see what would happen?

Comment: yes I get an error, it is treating it as passed value. If I passed as `expected=True` I get `got positional argument after named arguments.`

Comment: You should update your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. This is documented in the robot framework user guide in a section titled [Named Arguments](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#named-argument-syntax).

In your case, `par1` must be the first argument. So, to call it with named arguments you can do it like this:

```
test_method    ${par1}    expected=${True}    par3=${par3}
```